# Interaction of geomagnetism on free falling coil

Tags: electromagnetism, earth, geomagnetism

Take the Earth, or a similarly large body with an Electromagnetic field. For now - expect atmosphere.

Then take a much smaller object - say the size of bus, containing a coil with many windings.

If meters were attached to this coil - would an EMF be induced in it, and
Simplifying so the object would be travelling at terminal velocity (ignoring the initial acceleration), could this be calculated or predicted?

Comment: If the magnetic flux through the coil is changing then yes, there would be an EMF and if you knew the relevant parameters then yes, you could predict it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Flux_through_a_surface_and_EMF_around_a_loop